Angular property does not exist : Using leaflet and leaflet-gpx in Ionic 7 Angular 18 application
I am trying to display a GPX file on leaflet into my Ionic Angular application by using GPX plugin for Leaflet. In VS Code, everything looks fine but when I run Ionic Serve, I get the following error : Property 'GPX' does not exist on type 'typeof import("TestLeaflet/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.
Here is how to reproduce the issue :

ionic start TestLeaflet blank (select Angular and Standalone)
npm install leaflet
npm install @types/leaflet --save-dev
npm install leaflet-gpx
npm install @types/leaflet-gpx --save-dev

Here is the content of the file app.component.ts :
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonApp, IonRouterOutlet],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  private initMap(): void{
    const options = {
      async: true,
      marker_options: {
        startIconUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-gpx@1.7.0/pin-icon-start.png',
        endIconUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-gpx@1.7.0/pin-icon-end.png',
        shadowUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-gpx@1.7.0/pin-shadow.png'
      }
    }

    const url = '../assets/gpx/rando.gpx';

    const map = L.map('map');
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
      }).addTo(map);
    
    new L.GPX(url, options).on('loaded', (e) => {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      }).addTo(map);
  }
}

So far everything is good in VS Code, but when I run Ionic serve, I get the following error :
Property 'GPX' does not exist on type 'typeof import("Projects/TestLeaflet/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'. [ng] 35     new L.GPX(url, options).on('loaded', (e) => {
What am I missing ?
Thanks for your help !

The error is correct because L imported is from 'leaflet' and there is no GPX definition in types/leaflet, but indeed there is one in types/leaflet-gpx.
Does maybe updating your import to import * as L from 'leaflet-gpx'; solve your problem?
Later edit:
Another solution, maybe try just adding the GPX import import * as LGPX from 'leaflet-gpx'; and then in your component do new LGPX.GPX(url, options... (got this idea from this example they provide)

Thanks for your help !


When I try your firts idea : import * as L from 'leaflet-gpx'; I still have the same error on GPX and on every other leaflet objects such as TileLayer, Map etc...


When I try import * as LGPX from 'leaflet-gpx';, I get the following error :
Property 'GPX' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/TestLeaflet/node_modules/@types/leaflet-gpx/index")'.


